# probability, please help on bayes question

Tags: probability, random-variables, random

I dont need exact answer, I just need help to judge wether my following method is correct or not.

Question:A physician has 5 patients. There are treatments A and B. Physician gives treament A to 3 randomly selected patients, and B to the other 2. Suppose that treament A produce a cure in any patient with a probability of 0.3, and B with 0.6. What is the probability that the two treatments will produce the same number of cures?

My attempt:

Let

X= # of cure in treament A
Y=# of cure in treament B

P(X=Y)=P(X=0,Y=0)+P(X=1,Y=1)+P(X=2,Y=2)
=P(X=0)P(Y=0)+P(X=1)P(Y=1)+P(X=2)P(Y=2)

P(X=0)=(p)^3*(1-p)^2, but I need to figure out what is p.

now comes to my question. For treament A, **P(Cure|treament A)=0.3 as given in the problem. My question is should I use this number or P(Cure And treament A)=P(A)*P(Cure|treament A)** to fill in the "p" in the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup is correct, we want 
$$\Pr(X=0)\Pr(Y=0)+\Pr(X=1)\Pr(Y=1)+\Pr(X=2)\Pr(Y=2).$$

We have $\Pr(X=0)=(0.7)^3$ and $\Pr(Y=0)=(0.4)^2$.

For $\Pr(X=1)$, the right expression is $\binom{3}{1}(0.3)(0.7)^2$. Similarly, $\Pr(Y=1)=\binom{2}{1}(0.6)(0.4)$.

Finally, $\Pr(X=2)=\binom{3}{2}(0.3)^2(0.7)$ and $\Pr(Y=2)=(0.6)^2$.

**Remark:** There is nothing particularly Bayesian about the calculation. The random variables $X$ and $Y$ have binomial distribution, with parameters fully specified in the statement of the problem.

Comment: can you please see update?

Comment: The bolded part in the question.

Comment: Calculating anything like $p^3(1-p)^2$ is in any case the wrong way to proceed. There are two distinct $p$'s in the problem, $p=0.3$ associated with the random variable $X$, and $p=0.6$ associated with the random variable $Y$.

Comment: @kou, It is: $P(X=x) = {3 \choose x} p^{x}(1-p)^{3-x}$ where $p = 0.3 = P(\text{Cure}\mid \text{treatment A})$, and $P(Y=y)={2 \choose y} q^y (1-q)^{2-y}$ where $q=0.6=P(\text{Cure}\mid \text{treatment B})$

Comment: You don't need to fiddle with $P(\text{Cure}\cap\text{treatment A})$ or $P(\text{treatment A})$ because you know which patient received which treatment.